# SharePoint 2013 Pre-Requisite Package

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell

Is it possible to download all the pre-requisite files as one zip file from somewhere?

I have a requirement to install SharePoint 2013 but some of the links I can find for the pre-requisite files seem to be broken.

I have wasted a day trying to locate the files on the Microsoft site.

I have tried the auto installer powershell script but it fails for some files.

Comment: do you know which are broken?

Answer (score 3):

You can use powershell script to download and install all prerequisite files.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/DownloadInstall-SharePoint-e6df9eb8

Answer (score 1):

I really like the concept of AutoSPSourceBuilder. Check here:

https://autospsourcebuilder.codeplex.com/

The steps I did:

1. Download it
2. Unzip it somewhere on your PC
3. Mount the SharePoint Server iso to your computer
4. open Powershell as Administrator
5. Navigate to your unziped location. Mine is `C:\Users\Patrick\Downloads\AutoSPSourceBuilder`
6. Type: `.\AutoSPSourceBuilder.ps1 -GetPrerequisites $true -Languages de-de`

I did directly include the language package. Then you are also able to select a culmulative update.

*End of the story:* You have everything in one! I did the last three weeks two installations of SharePoint Server 2013 on-prem and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

@AmitKotha 's given link is awesome. Below is the `PowerShell` script which will download all of the `Pre requisite` into a folder.

> **Note**: Read this [Download and Install SharePoint 2013 Prerequisites on
>   Windows Server 2012](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/DownloadInstall-SharePoint-e6df9eb8) and download the script, then you will get a better idea.

**Start** your script with a parameter which holds the path where you want to store all the pre requisite, and import a module `BitsTransfer`

```
param([string] $SharePoint2013Path = $(Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the directory path to where you wish to save the SharePoint 2013 Prerequisite files.")) 

# Import Required Modules
Import-Module BitsTransfer
```

**Array which contains links to all the Pre requisties**

```
# Specify download url's for SharePoint 2013 prerequisites
$DownloadUrls = (
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/3/9138773A-505D-43E2-AC08-9A77E1E0490B/1033/x64/sqlncli.msi", # Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/0/0/E0060D8F-2354-4871-9596-DC78538799CC/Synchronization.msi", # Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/7/A678AB47-496B-4907-B3D4-0A2D280A13C0/WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe", # Windows Server App Fabric
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/5/7B51D8D1-20FD-4BF0-87C7-4714F5A1C313/AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe", # Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/7/2/D72FD747-69B6-40B7-875B-C2B40A6B2BDD/Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu", #Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01D06854-CA0C-46F1-ADBA-EBF86010DCC6/rtm/MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi", # Microsoft Identity Extensions
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/D/91DA8796-BE1D-46AF-8489-663AB7811517/setup_msipc_x64.msi", # Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/9/8F93DBBD-896B-4760-AC81-646F61363A6D/WcfDataServices.exe" # Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
                )
```

**Function which downloads the pre requisite**

```
function DownLoadPreRequisites() 
{ 
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "====================================================================="
    Write-Host "      Downloading SharePoint 2013 Prerequisites Please wait..." 
    Write-Host "====================================================================="
    $ReturnCode = 0 
    foreach ($DownLoadUrl in $DownloadUrls) 
    { 
        ## Get the file name based on the portion of the URL after the last slash 
        $FileName = $DownLoadUrl.Split('/')[-1] 
        Try 
        { 
            ## Check if destination file already exists 
            If (!(Test-Path "$SharePoint2013Path\$FileName")) 
            { 
                ## Begin download 
                Start-BitsTransfer -Source $DownLoadUrl -Destination $SharePoint2013Path\$fileName -DisplayName "Downloading `'$FileName`' to $SharePoint2013Path" -Priority High -Description "From $DownLoadUrl..." -ErrorVariable err 
                If ($err) {Throw ""} 
            } 
            Else 
            { 
                Write-Host " - File $FileName already exists, skipping..." 
            } 
        } 
        Catch 
        { 
            $ReturnCode = -1 
            Write-Warning " - An error occurred downloading `'$FileName`'" 
            Write-Error $_ 
            break 
        } 
    } 
    Write-Host " - Done downloading Prerequisites required for SharePoint 2013" 
    return $ReturnCode 
}
```

**Usage**: Just make a call at the end of the script

```
DownLoadPreRequisites
```